# Azure - ASP.NET WEB API - Long Response time on 2+ operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, performance-testing, response-time

I have a "simple" method in which I have a stopwatch that tracks the timing of the for parts.

My stopwatch told me:

- Part1: 2ms
- Part2: 20ms
- Part3: 300ms
- Part4: 5ms

TOTAL: 327ms

When I call my service from Postman the "Time" of the single call works like this:

- First call: 1.8s
- Second call: 8s
- Third call: 8s
- and so on

So, there are two questions:

- Why the method tooks 300ms and the response 2 secs? (uploading 20kb attachment)
- Why the second and later call took 4 times the time needed for the first one?

Working with a Web App 2 Core 3.5GB Ram on Azure

Thanks!

Comment: Ask your telemetry, App Insights has a Performance blade - you go through a little setup, it collects a few things and you get profiler traces! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-web-monitor-performance

Comment: I connected Application Insight but he seems to work only with the ActionController and not with the ApiController. Where can I change his behauvior?

Comment: Did you enable the profiler from the Performance blade? It shouldn't matter what type of application it is, the profiler collects and massages ETL data.

Comment: I find out that the File.IO.Write / File.IO.Delete is destroying performance. How can I save for local operations a file on my webservice w/o impact on performance?

Comment: Write to `d:\local`, it's a temporary drive that gets wiped on Web App restart (so don't use it for anything remotely important). I believe it's exposed as %TEMP% or %TMP% as well.

Comment: Yup, check all predefined env vars here: `https://{appname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml`